# How to push data to azure devops using python

Tags: python, git, rest, azure-devops

I am trying to push data to azure devops using python.
Here is how the paths to the original data (local) look like

```
original_paths = [
        "c:/user/dir1/filename1.txt",
        "c:/user/dir2/filename1.py",
        "c:/user/dir2/filenamex.json"
    ]
```

I would like to create folders in devops ommitting `c:/user/`, so I will push:

```
data_to_push = [
        "dir1/filename1.txt",
        "dir2/filename1.py",
        "dir2/filenamex.json"
    ]
```

The following code snippet only establishes the connection to the repo.

```
def push_to_azure_devops():
    from azure.devops.connection import Connection
    from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
    from git import Repo, remote

    organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/repo-name'
    user = "username"
    password = "q578w645746748w5zt"
    credentials = BasicAuthentication(username='', password=password)
    connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

    git_client = connection.clients.get_git_client()

    # I am stuck from here.
    create_push = git_client.create_push(push="???", repository_id="RepoID", project="ProjectName")

    original_paths = [
        "c/user/dir1/filename1.txt",
        "c/user/dir2/filename1.py",
        "c/user/dir2/filenamex.json"
    ]

    data_to_push = [
        "dir1/filename1.txt",
        "dir2/filename1.py",
        "dir2/filenamex.json"
    ]

    remote.Remote.add(...)
    remote.Remote.commit(...)
    remote.Remote.push(...)
```

Any help would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference below Python sample to call the Azure DevOps REST API "[**Pushes - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)":

```
import base64
import requests

organization = 'xxxx'
project = 'xxxx'
repository = 'xxxx'
oldObjectId = 'xxxx'
url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/pushes?api-version=7.0'

ado_pat = 'xxxx'
b64token = base64.b64encode((":" + ado_pat).encode()).decode()

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Basic {b64token}'
}

folderPath = "C:/user/"
files = [
    "dir1/filename1.txt",
    "dir2/filename1.py",
    "dir2/filenamex.json"
]

changes = []

for file in files:
    filePath = f"{folderPath}{file}"
    fr = open(filePath, "r")
    content = fr.read()
    change = {
        "changeType": "add",
        "item": {
             "path": file
        },
        "newContent": {
            "content": content,
            "contentType": "rawtext"
        }
    }

    changes.append(change)


body = {
    "refUpdates": [
        {
            "name": "refs/heads/main",
            "oldObjectId": oldObjectId
        }
    ],
    "commits": [
        {
            "comment": "Add 3 new files.",
            "changes": changes
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
response_content = response.content
print(response_content)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The **`oldObjectId`** is the **`ObjectId`** of the branch ref (e.g., **`refs/heads/main`** in my above sample) that you want to push the new files to in the Azure git repository.

You can use the REST API "[**Refs - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)" to get the current **`ObjectId`** of a branch ref in the Azure git repository. Then pass that Id to the request body of "**Pushes - Create**" API.

---

**UPDATE_2:**

The '[**`open()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)' function in Python can handle files as either **`text`** mode or **`binary`** mode.

- **`open(path/to/text/file, "rt")`**: will handle the file as text mode to read. For example, text files, code files, json files, etc...
- **`open(path/to/binary/file, "rb")`**: will handle the file as binary mode to read. For example, images.
- Since this method handles file as text mode to read by default, the codes "**`open(path/to/text/file)`**", "**`open(path/to/text/file, "r")`**" and "**`open(path/to/text/file, "rt")`**" are equivalent.

The '**`open()`**' function cannot handle tabular files. If you want to handle tabular files in Python, you can reference below articles:

- For CSV File: [**CSV File Reading and Writing**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
- For Excel File (**`.xlsx`**, **`.xls`**): [**Read Excel with Python Pandas**](https://pythonbasics.org/read-excel/)

---

Comment: @Kyv, I have updated my above answer with more information. Check and try it.

Comment: Thank you @Bright Ran-MSFT. By the way, do you have any idea how to read tabular files, such as csv, parquet or excel? With `open(filePath, "r")` I get an error about encoding. `encoding='utf-8'` does not work. `encoding='latin-1'` seems to work but the content is not understandable by humans.

Comment: @Kyv, I have shared more information in my answer (see **UPDATE_2**).